# IllegalArgumentException porting from Eclipse RCP 3 to 4

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I would like to port my Eclipse RCP application from 3.x to 4.x.
I've now set up my project and it builds with no errors. 
Upon executing the application it throws an `IllegalArgumentException` when loading the PerspectiveSwitcherToolbar.
The `PerspectiveSwitcherToolbar` extends `ContributionItem`. Originally it extended `ControlContibution` but we changed this as it needed to be shared over multiple perspectives. [Here](https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/03/31/replacing-the-perspective-switcher-in-rcp-apps/) is the tutorial explaining how this was done.

```
!MESSAGE Loaded class is of incorrect type: expected(org.eclipse.ui.menus.WorkbenchWindowControlContribution) got (PerspectiveSwitcherToolbar)
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Loaded class is of incorrect type: expected(org.eclipse.ui.menus.WorkbenchWindowControlContribution) got (PerspectiveSwitcherToolbar)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.util.Util.safeLoadExecutableExtension(Util.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.CompatibilityWorkbenchWindowControlContribution.construct(CompatibilityWorkbenchWindowControlContribution.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolControlContribution.createControl(ToolControlContribution.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ControlContribution.fill(ControlContribution.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.update(ToolBarManager.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarManagerRenderer.subscribeTopicUpdateToBeRendered(ToolBarManagerRenderer.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.di.UIEventObjectSupplier$UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventObjectSupplier.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4567)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.di.UIEventObjectSupplier$UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventObjectSupplier.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.UIElementImpl.setVisible(UIElementImpl.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarContributionRecord.updateVisibility(ToolBarContributionRecord.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarManagerRenderer$2.changed(ToolBarManagerRenderer.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.runAndTrack(EclipseContext.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarManagerRenderer.processAddition(ToolBarManagerRenderer.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarManagerRenderer.generateContributions(ToolBarManagerRenderer.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarManagerRenderer.processContribution(ToolBarManagerRenderer.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarManagerRenderer.createWidget(ToolBarManagerRenderer.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:749)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimBarRenderer.processContents(TrimBarRenderer.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$1.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:749)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1096)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at com.Application.start(Application.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1471)
```

The problem specified is that the `PerspectiveSwitcherToolbar` should extend `WorkbenchWindowControlContribution`. Currently it extends `ContributionItem` which works fine in RCP 3.

I've tried changing the `PerspectiveSwitcherToolbar` to make it extend `WorkbenchWindowControlContribution` but the `createControl` method isn't called at the very start which is needed.

What are some possible solutions to this?

Comment: Where does `createPartControl` come in to this? That isn't a method of `ContributionItem` or `WorkbenchWindowControlContribution`.

Comment: `WorkbenchWindowControlContribution` has a `createPartControl` method. If I understand correctly I now need to change from `ContributionItem` to `WorkbenchWindowControlContribution` as is mentioned [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=427475) in a bug report.

Comment: `WorkbenchWindowControlContribution` has a `createControl` method, it does not have `createPartControl`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! I've updated the question.

Comment: Looking at `CompatibilityWorkbenchWindowControlContribution` shown in that stack trace it will call the `createControl` method of the class extending `WorkbenchWindowControlContribution` immediately after the code that is failing - are you saying this code is running too late? The code is running from the tool bar renderer which is pretty early in the startup.

Comment: I believe it called the `fill` method in `ContributionItem` first. Now I've ported it to RCP 4 it doesn't like using the `ContributionItem` so I need to swap for `WorkbenchWindowControlContribution`. I can't figure out how to do this as it seems to now call `createControl` at the end meaning the toolbar is added in the wrong place. Also the toolbar doesn't have any items in it.